# HTML Page cant scroll down and content is hidden behind footer

Tags: html, css

So I can't scroll down on my html page. I already thought of some things that might cause that but I still don't how how to fix it. I have a footer that is sticked to the bottom of the side and all the content is behind that footer. Some guy told me just to add body {padding-bottom: "height of footer"} but that doesnt work for me because my footer changes height if the screen res is something different.

Comment: Most likely this is because of `overflow: hidden`. But it's hard to understand without the code.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov thats my footer css : display: flex; justify-content: center; position: absolute; and thats my html, body: box-sizing: border-box ;margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height: 100%;

Comment: This is the normal behavior of an absolute block. Add margin-bottom for content that is hidden.

Comment: QPQ JXJ, welcome to SO. Could you please add code to your question ideally using a 'snippet', so that people can see your HTML, CSS and run it, to see how it behaves? It will surely add to your chance of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your footer is position absolute or fixed(or something of the sort). This allows your footer to be displayed at all times, but other elements on the page will have no awareness of this (thus are hidden behind).

So you have 2 options:

option 1: allow footer to not show at all times, and
use something like css flex, where you can define your elements so that the middle content has flex-grow. (and likely some padding too)

option 2: add some sort of padding to the main content so that it leaves room for the footer.
If you can't be certain of the footer's size, you can always put in some restraints on your footer and have the maximum height be accounted for by your content. that way you will always be able to see all your content, worst case scenario you get extra white space.

ex: If your footer can be up to 20vh high, you can set the content to have a vh of 120. (You can also use padding or margins, whatever works)